# convert the lines of a file into numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a files in which data is something like this

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
[4,2,3,4,5,6]
[3,12,3,34,5]
[3,4,5,6,7,8]
[2,3,4,5,6,6]
[2,3,4,5,5,4,3]
[1,2,3,23,2,1]
```

i just want to convert this into numpy array, something like this

```
[[1,2,3,4,5],[4,2,3,4,5,6]]
```

I tried following code:

```
import ast
import numpy as np
a = np.array([])
with open("test.txt","r") as f:
        for line in f:
                line = ast.literal_eval(line)
                np.append(line,a)
```

it is only giving `[]`

Comment: _I tried following code:_ It might prove useful if you also were to divulge what happened next.

Comment: @PaulPanzer sure editing

Comment: Btw. I think you want to swap arguments of `append` and more importantly **reassign** to a. `np.append` does not work in-place.

Comment: BTW, this isn't going to be a proper array, since the dimensions aren't regular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **[array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)** method in numpy.

```
import ast
from numpy import array

p = "PATH_TO_INPUT_FILE"
data = []
with open(p,"r") as f:
    for i in f.readlines():
        data.append(ast.literal_eval(i.strip()))
data = array(data)
print(data)
print(type(data))
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] [4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] [3, 12, 3, 34, 5] [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6] [2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3] [1, 2, 3, 23, 2, 1]]
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = []
    for line in f:
        words = line.replace('[', ''). replace(']', '').replace('\n', '').split(',')
        data.append([int(i) for i in words])
```

if you want numpy array:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = []
    for line in f:
        words = line.replace('[', ''). replace(']', '').replace('\n', '').split(',')
        data.append(np.array([int(i) for i in words]))
```

Comment: it is giving: [array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), array([4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), array([ 3, 12,  3, 34,  5]), array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]), array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6]), array([2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3]), array([ 1,  2,  3, 23,  2,  1])]

Comment: The first one will give you a list of lists (which is what you wanted in your question). The second one will produce list of np arrays. Use np.array(data) to the first output to get 2d np array

Comment: @ggupta What do you expect from numpy? Your lists don't have the same dimension, how are they supposed to be converted into an n x m array?